# Using build with pyproject.toml produces a dynamic version that does not seem to match git tags

Tags: version, pyproject.toml, pip-tools, setuptools-scm

My pyproject.toml file contains:

```
[project]
name = "projecta"
dynamic = ["version"]

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools >= 61.0",
            "setuptools-scm >= 8.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools_scm]
version_file = "projecta/_version.py"
```

Python 3.10.12

setuptools-scm==8.0.4

pip-tools==7.3.0

git version 2.34.1

$ git describe
v0.1.9

$ git describe --tags
v0.1.9

What gets created from 'python -m build' is:

```
projecta-0.1.10.dev0+gf3c0ecd.d20240214-py3-none-any.whl
```

How is the version determined? The patch generated does not match what is in the latest tag.

I tried adding new tags: git tag -a . Nothing produces a build that matches the latest tag. I tried looking through git output to find a version that matches what build is producing and have not found anything that matches. I committed all changes and then added a new tag. Still getting a newer version than specified along with devx on all built versions.